# Making class object as synchronized variable

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

```
    private static class RunningMutex {}
    private static class ObserveMutex {}

    private static volatile RunningMutex runningMutex = new ImportActionRunningMutex();
    private static volatile ObserveMutex observeMutex = new ImportActionObserveMutex();



    synchronized (observeMutex) {......}  .... (1)
    synchronized (runningMutex) {......}  .....(2)
```

Is it a good practice to have code something like above ? I am currently refactoring a big code which is not working properly and I found out these lines. I would like to know if there is some alternative to the above code.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Could you rephrase it? Or *explain* what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can have anything. But some explanation of the problem would be nice...

Comment: Your code isn't locking on the monitor associated with the class, it's still locking on a monitor associated with the instace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an uncommon pattern when you want to isolate different locks from eachother in the same class, or when you want to share the same lock across different classes. It's not strictly necessary to create specified classes for each different lock (could just use different Object instances), but it helps a lot when you're analyzing thread dumps as it will be clear which thread owns which monitor.

The danger is that you can create dead-lock situations unless you're careful (thread X locks monitor A, thread Y locks monitor B, thread X tries to lock monitor B, thread Y tries to lock monitor A).

Comment: So if i create two instances of same class instead of having two instances of differnce classes will there be any deadlock situations....???

Comment: There is still a risk of deadlock, yes. Always when you are using more than one lock in an application, you have to be mindful to not write code that risk creating a deadlock. One clear alarmbell is if you have a method with a synchronized block using one monitor and another synchronized block inside it using another monitor.